# How to force a curl request in a PHP method to fail for a unit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, curl, code-coverage

I'm covering some legacy code with unit tests. I have some code that looks like this<sup>†</sup> (I have removed the bits not relevant to this question):

```php
    public function search($query) {
        $query = urlencode($query);
        $url = 'https://example.com/search.php?q=' . $query;

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        ));
        $data = curl_exec($curl);

        if (!$data) {
            throw new Exception('An error occurred while trying to process the request.');
        }
    }
```

How can I force the `curl` request to fail so that the `Exception` gets `throw`n? I'm not allowed to change the existing code in a method until it is fully covered. The URL is hard-coded except for the query string, so I can't change that and the query string is correctly URL encoded with `urlencode()`, so I can't pass through a badly formatted string.

Is there a safe string length I could exceed for the query? Perhaps a setting I could change with `ini_set()`?

<sub><sup>† I'm aware of the bugs in the code</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

cURL favours couple of environmental variables for establishing communications and they can be used to affect curl operation without tweaking tested php code.

These variables are:

- http_proxy
- https_proxy
- no_proxy

So you can preserve the current values of those variables in `setUp()` and restore them in `tearDown()`.

Following code will break your curl for sure:

```php
putenv("https_proxy=localhost:5678");
putenv("no_proxy=blah-blah-blah");
```

Comment: `curl` quite happily retrieved the page despite the `https_proxy` setting.

Comment: are you sure that putenv had an effect? - please check getenv to read value back (sometimes putenv is disabled for security reasons). Also I added extra env var "no_proxy" into consideration. If you have "no_proxy" var set to "*", then "https_proxy" variable is ignored so it makes sense to reset it as well.

Comment: `getenv()` returns `false` for all of `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, and `NO_PROXY`. When I set them with `putenv()` they return the values set to them.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php "`local_only` Set to true to only return local environment variables (set by the operating system or putenv)". I think the local environment variables have no effect on `curl`.

Comment: they (local overrides via putenv) have an effect in my test. Otherwise I would not post an answer in the first place :-) It looks like php-extension (or libcurl itself) ignores environment variables (regardless of method used to set them) for some reason in your setup.

Comment: I'm on Windows. Maybe that makes a difference. What's your environment?

Comment: my env is ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205015/discussion-between-cj-dennis-and-maxim-sagaydachny).