# Setting environment variables within PHP works for one user but not another

Tags: php, windows, environment-variables, command-line-interface

A user has been helping me with a problem ([How to force a curl request in a PHP method to fail for a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59517271/1166898)). They suggested doing `putenv('all_proxy=localhost:5678');` so I can force `curl` to fail dynamically in a unit test (I changed `http_proxy` / `https_proxy` to `all_proxy` because it does all protocols).

This works perfectly on their Ubuntu box, but I can't get it to work on <s>either</s> my Windows 10 box <s>or Ubuntu box</s>. If I set `all_proxy` from the command prompt, the `curl` requests always fail, so it is taking notice of the variable when it can find it. I changed their script slightly and that seems to have got it working on Ubuntu.

Is there some setting in `php.ini` that controls whether `putenv()` can override variables from the environment or not? Why does the dynamic environment variable work on <s>their setup but not on either of mine</s> Ubuntu but not Windows?

#### Test script

```php
<?php

function search() {
  $url = 'x3m.dev';

  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  ]);
  $data = curl_exec($curl);

  if (!$data) {
    throw new Exception('An error occurred while trying to process the request.');
  }
  return $data;
}

function do_curl_request() {
  echo getenv('all_proxy') . "\n\n";
  try {
    echo search();
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
  echo "\n\n";
}

echo "========== first run without proxy\n";
do_curl_request();

putenv('all_proxy=localhost:5678');
echo "========== second run with proxy override\n";
do_curl_request();
```

It should work the first time and throw an exception the second time. On Windows it works both times if `all_proxy` is not set as a Windows environment variable, and throws an exception both times if `all_proxy` is set.

#### Windows (incorrect)

```
========== first run without proxy


<html>
<head></head>
<body>.</body>
</html>

========== second run with proxy override
localhost:5678

<html>
<head></head>
<body>.</body>
</html>
```

#### Ubuntu (correct)

```
========== first run without proxy


<html>
<head></head>
<body>.</body>
</html>

========== second run with proxy override
localhost:5678

An error occurred while trying to process the request.
```

Comment: **localhost:5678** have you setup your localhost proxy?

Comment: @Popeye No. The whole point is that it should fail because there's no such service at `localhost:5678`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

It was a bug and that was patched in PHP 7.3.17 and 7.4.5 (March 2020). There is no known workaround for earlier versions.

---

Are you sitting comfortably? Then let's begin!

1. This bug only exists on Windows
2. I created a [PHP bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79051)
3. This bug was previously noticed and [fixed in PHP 5](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66265), but only for non-thread-safe versions:

   - PHP 5.4.36 non-thread-safe (17 December 2014)
   - PHP 5.5.20 non-thread-safe (26 November 2014)
   - PHP 5.6.4 non-thread-safe (27 November 2014)
4. The bug was marked as "partially fixed", but got accidentally closed anyway, preventing further work on the bug as it fell off people's radar
5. There are two possible internal calls to get/set environment variables:

   - `SetEnvironmentVariable()` / `GetEnvironmentVariable()` (thread-safe)
   - `putenv()` / `getenv()` (non-thread-safe)
6. cURL uses `getenv()` which can't see changes made by `SetEnvironmentVariable()`
7. A [cURL bug report](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2020-01/0006.html) has now been created

[A fix for cURL](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/4774) was merged on 12 February 2020. This was released in cURL 7.69 on 4 March 2020.

A note on the PHP bug report I created says:

> libcurl 7.69.1 has been released which fixes this issue, and will
>   be used for the PHP 7.3.17 and 7.4.5 Windows builds, so I'm
>   closing this ticket.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to recognize that PHP does not import anything from the user's environment. It has it's own self-contained environment which is per-request (i.e. it's cleaned up with every `RSHUTDOWN` event in the interpreter). Anything you do within php (i.e. `putenv()`) lives strictly within that request. What you do in your shell will have no effect on PHP's environment.

### [putenv](http://php.net/putenv)

> Adds **setting** to the server environment. The environment variable will only exist for the duration of the current request. At the end of the request the environment is restored to its original state.

Comment: `If I set all_proxy from the command prompt, the curl requests always fail, so it is taking notice of the variable when it can find it.` Your answer is counter to what I can verify experimentally.

Comment: I assure you it is not. It would be a huge security issue if it did. PHP's environment is self-contained by design.

Comment: May I suggest that you try setting the environment variable and running the script that the other user gave me?

Comment: The PHP code in question is not the issue here. It is the fact that you believe you can set the environment variable from your command prompt and that PHP will magically import that environment variable. **It won't**. You **must** set that environment variable inside of PHP by using `putenv()`.

Comment: Please explain how I can change PHP's behaviour by setting an environment variable from the command prompt. (not hypothetically, but how the real life behaviour actually changes when you rerun the script)

Comment: Whatever it is that causes your script to behave differently has nothing to do with PHP importing environment variables. That much I can assure you of. Why it is your script is behaving in an unexpected way I could not tell you. That would would require further debugging. Though your conclusion is not based in fact. I'd suggest looking at the specific curl error information with [`curl_error`](http://php.net/curl-error) to get more useful information to go on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205174/discussion-between-cj-dennis-and-sherif).